# GCP - Google Cloud Workstations

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp

We have deployed google cloud workstations and we need to restrict the number of the created cloud workstations by users, i.e. each user should be able to provision one and only one workstation.
Any idea how to meet these requirements?

Thanks

Comment: I am not aware of a Google Cloud method via constraints, etc. Consider setting up audit log monitoring to detect when a user creates a workstation.